# Seam/JSF - Multiple messages on login failure?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam

I'm using JBoss Seam 2.2 in my application, and am seeing some strange behavior in the way login failures are handled.  When a user fails authentication using #{identity.login}, I see multiple JSF messages being displayed.  One has the message key `org.jboss.seam.loginFailed`, while the other has the key `org.jboss.seam.NotLoggedIn`.  I would obviously expect the first message, as that corresponds to entering an incorrect password.  However, why is the second message being displayed?  There's no reason for it.  I'd like to be able to remove that from the list of messages displayed when it's not necessary, but I haven't found a way to do so.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`org.jboss.seam.security.FacesSecurityEvents`** adds the **`org.jboss.seam.NotLoggedIn`** message when it observes the **`org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn`** event. The **`org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn`** event is raised when an attempt is made to access a resource that requires a certain level of authorization, but the user is not logged in.

After authentication fails, is the user being redirected to a protected page? Do you have any custom login logic that might be accessing a protected resource?

I suggest providing your pages.xml, components.xml, and any custom authentication logic you might have.

Comment: The issue is I had a global redirect to handle #{identity.login()} and redirect the user to their home page.  However, I didn't have a rule that checked to see if the login was actually successful, so Seam was trying to redirect the (non-authenticated) user to their home page which was being blocked by a restrict statement.  Thanks for your help!